# Error while Patching Security Patch (SUPEE-6285) - NoItems.phtml (SOLVED)

Tags: security, patches, supee-6285

I'm trying to apply the new patch release today `SUPEE-6285`  but I get this error :

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
>   Hunk #1 FAILED at 31. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml.rej

I did not change anything to `noItems.phtml`, the file exist, and he has the good rights.

Also; It is stated with the patch that you must first implement `SUPEE-5994` to ensure `SUPEE-6285` works properly, which I have already done.

Magento 1.9.1.1
Patch : `PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-07-09-03-34.sh`

> PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-07-09-03-34.sh: 24: 127: not
>   found PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-07-09-03-34.sh: 24: 127:
>   not found PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-07-09-03-34.sh: 29:
>   0: not found Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>   -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> patching file app/Mage.php patching file
>   app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php patching
>   file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php patching
>   file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php patching
>   file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php patching
>   file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php patching
>   file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
>   patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
>   patching file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php patching
>   file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
>   patching file
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml Hunk #1
>   succeeded at 99 with fuzz 2 (offset 1 line). patching file
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
>   Hunk #1 FAILED at 31. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml.rej
>   patching file
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
>   patching file
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
>   patching file
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
>   Hunk #1 succeeded at 25 with fuzz 2. patching file
>   app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml Hunk
>   1 succeeded at 97 with fuzz 2. patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess patching file
>   downloader/Maged/Controller.php patching file
>   downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php patching file
>   downloader/lib/.htaccess patching file
>   downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml patching file
>   downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml patching file
>   downloader/template/login.phtml patching file
>   downloader/template/settings.phtml patching file errors/processor.php

**EDIT (SOLVED) :**

I've replacing the noItemps.phtml of my live version with the noItems.phtml of a fresh magento 1.9.1.1, then apply the patch again, and it works (well, almost, see below). Somehow, it has been modify.

Now I've the same error for packages_prepare.phtml, and this solution doesn't work. But that's for another thread...

Comment: `packages_prepare.phtml` has been updated in SUPEE-5994 which is not yet included in Magento 1.9.1.1, so you have to apply it before SUPEE-6285

Comment: Yes I did that like requested by magento but didn't work anyway, and I solve the issue here, even if it was deleted http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73690/not-able-to-apply-security-patch-supee-6285-packages-prepare-phtml-solved

Answer (score 2):

Patches aren't tolerant to inconsistent source files.

If they in any way do not match what is expected (even from something as simple as a line break), it can cause the patch to be rejected.

If you were already running 1.9.1.1, you'd probably be easier just grabbing a fresh 1.9.2.0 source and replacing your current source with it.

The patches are pre-applied to 1.9.2.0, so nothing further is required.

Comment: Actually, I think it's a bad advice, but it's just my opinion. Unless you have time and severely test the new version against your theme and installed module, blindly upgrading often causes worse problems than just making the patch work. I've juste upraded from 1.6 to 1.9 few weeks ago and what a pain in the a**, really... I'm not ready to do it again.

Comment: Of course, testing goes without saying. But for the OP and his experience, its best he just grabs a fresh unmodified core to replace his modified core.

Answer (score 0):

please compare it with original file
http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml

Comment: Your version is the 1.9.2 version of the noItems file right ?